# mysql get value within a range from table

Tags: mysql

```
+------------+---------+
|    Column1 |  Column2|
+------------+---------+
|     25     |    5    |
|     30     |    5    |
|     35     |    5    |
|     40     |   5.5   |
|     45     |   5.5   |
|    100     |    6    |
+------------+---------+
```

let say i have table like above.

i want to get Column2 value based on number within a range of Column1.

example :
if input 24 or less, return 5
if my inputs are  30 or 32, should return me 5
if my input are 57, return me 5.5
if input 110, return 6

what sql should i run to get the value?

Comment: @od3n can you pls tell whats the column1 range to specify the value for column 2

Comment: @bew less than 25, 25 to 29.99, 30 to 39.99, 40 to 44.99, 45 to 99.99, 100 or more

Answer (score 5):

This will give the the closest result. Not quite sure if this is what you want

```
select column2
from your_table
order by abs($input - column1)
limit 1
```

Comment: i not sure why i cant get correct value with these values inside the table. 25 | 4.3, 30 | 4.5, 35 | 4.7, 40 | 4.7, 45 | 5.3, 50 | 5.5, 55 | 5.7, 100, 6. my input is 34. it return 4.7. the correct value is 4.5

Answer (score 1):

A solution:

```
SELECT 
    Column2 
FROM 
    TableName 
WHERE 
    Column1 >= $number ORDER BY Column1 ASC LIMIT 0,1
```